# How can you change state in a web component in a way that can be interpreted by history using vaadin-router?

Tags: typescript, vaadin, lit-element

I have a fairly simple LitElement custom component that I want to have an "editing" state for. Since I have all the information from the server already, I don't want to load a new component just for the purpose of showing an editing screen or reload the current component, but I *do* want to make it so that a user pressing the back button is brought out of the editing state. I'm not sure how to do both.

Simple example:

```
@customElement('my-element')
class MyElement extends LitElement {

  @property({ attribute: false }) private _editing = false;
  @property({ attribute: false }) private _data!: Data;

  public connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    // Loading stuff..
  }

  public render() {
    return this._editing
      ? html`
          <editing-control .data=${this._data}></editing-control>
        `
      : html`
          <details-control .data=${this._data}></details-control>
          <button @click=${this._onEditClick}>Edit</button>
        `;
  }

  private _onEditClick(e: Event) {
    this._editing = true;
  }
}
```

Note I'm using [Vaadin router](https://vaadin.com/router) for routing and the following approaches have problems

- Having the edit button add #editing to the url (either by having it be a link or changing the location with `Route.go` or `window.location.href`) causes the router to reconnect the component, triggering a re-load of the data and reset of state
- Attempting to listen to 'popstate', I get the notification after vaadin-router, so it changes to the previous location before I can modify its behavior
- using onBeforeLeave, I can't distinguish between an attempt to go back versus a legitimate request to go do a different page from the menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have something like this in your routes configuration

```
{
  path: '/foo',
  component: 'my-foo-component'
}
```

You should modify it and use `action` instead of `component`, in the action you need to return the same instance of the component

```
my fooElement = document.createElement('my-foo-component');
....

{
  path: '/foo',
  action: () => fooElement;
}
```

Comment: That is what I have yes. What are the negative implications of doing this? Obviously the constructor only gets called once so any initialized state has to be in connectedCallback, are there others? Will I need to clear any large pieces of state on disconnect for example?

Comment: Yes you have only one instance, thus, constructor is only once called. Router will detach/reattach the component when visiting the route again, so you can use those connected disconnected callbacks. There are also callbacks in router https://vaadin.github.io/vaadin-router/vaadin-router/#/classes/WebComponentInterface